# Server randomly freezes with no apparent reason

Tags: vps, apache2, crash

My server randomly freezes with no apparent reason. Because of that I decided to reinstall the system completely. Additionally, I installed apache2, PhpMyAdmin, PHP, symfony, composer, certbot. It worked fine for a few days, now, just a few hours ago it froze again. Website hosted doesn't response, I cannot log in via SSH or VNC. There are no logs between the freeze and restart. Server worked fine with this configuration for months. I asked support if they had any technical problems, they did not. I share with you my logs. Hope you can help me.

Config:

- VPS in Contabo.com
- 4vCPU, 8 GB RAM, 200 GB SSD, 200 Mbit/s Port
- Debian 10

Logs: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1lu6BIOQyTDDcwUE-b3BjTcNOrnuN4SIJ?usp=sharing

Comment: Find out whatever is on your system that writes 3 to drop_caches and make it stop immediately.

Comment: Networking is not working, you will need to power cycle the server and hope it comes back up. Or maybe contabo has some kind of console/ipmi access? You will not be able to do much of anything until the network is back up. Sorry you are having so much trouble with this node.

Comment: But this is not the first time, and server is immediately up after restart.

Comment: MichaelHampton And how should I do this?